# Printing element of array prints name of array instead

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to write a simulated shell program, with a history command that prints the 10 most recent entries in the shell. The problem is that when the history command is used, instead of printing the line typed, the name of addToHistory's internal array argument, "history" is printed for every entry.

Here is the code.

```
void addToHistory(char *line, char **history, int num) {
    // insert line into first element of history
    // move elements backward to make room
    if(num == 0) {
        history[0] = line;
    }
    else if (num > 1 && num < HISTORY_BUFFER) {
        printf("%d", num);
        printf("\n");
        for(int i = num-1;i > 0;i--) {
            history[i] = history[i-1];
        }
        history[0] = line;
    }
    else if (num > HISTORY_BUFFER) {
        printf("%d", num);
        printf("\n");
        for(int i = HISTORY_BUFFER-1;i > 0;i--) {
            history[i] = history[i-1];
    }
        history[0] = line;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];              /* command line arguments                 */
    char *history[HISTORY_BUFFER];
    char line[64];
    int  should_run = 1;                     /* flag to determine when to exit program */
    int  num = 0;
    while (should_run) {
        printf("osh> ");
        fflush(stdout);
        gets(line);                          /*   read in the command line             */
        printf("\n");
        parse(line, args);                   // function for splitting input into seperate strings; works fine
        if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0)  { /* is it an "exit"?                       */
            should_run = 0;                  /*   exit if it is                        */
        }
        else if (strcmp(args[0], "history") == 0) {
            if (num == 0) {
                printf("No commands in history. Please enter a command and try again\n");
            }
            else if (num < 10) {
                for(int i = 0;i < num;i++) {
                    printf("%d ", i);
                    printf(history[i]);
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
            else {
                for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
                    printf("%d ", i);
                    printf(history[i]);
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }
        /* snip */
        else {
            addToHistory(line, history, num);
            num++;
            // executeProcess(args);
        }
    }
}
```

The output produced after 10 entries is something like

```
osh> history
0 history
1 history
2 history
3 history
4 history
5 history
6 history
7 history
8 history
9 history
```

where "history" should instead be whatever was typed into the shell at the time. After one entry the output is simply `0 history', so the behavior is present in all iterations of`addToProcess`.

Comment: You should not use `gets()` ever under any circumstances. It was deprecated in C99, and completely removed from the language with C11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are storing a pointer to the string passed into the `addToHistory` function in every element of the array. Since you overwrite this string when a new command is entered, when you display the history, every entry will show the last command, which in this case is `history`.

You need to make a copy of the string to store into the history array. The easiest way to do so is to make a copy of the string.

Instead of just storing the string in the array

```
history[0] = line;
```

use the [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) function

```
history[0] = strdup(line);
```

Note that `strdup` dynamically allocates memory for the new string, so you'll have to make sure that you call `free` on any entries of the array that are removed or you'll have a memory leak. You will also need to free any entries which have been allocated before your program exits.